# BigQuery JavaScript UDF to merge lists/arrays of values

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

So I have these columns, `col1` thru `colx` are all of type `STRING/TEXT`:

```
id   |   col1   |    col2   | col3     | ...
-----|----------|-----------|----------|------
1    |[{"a":1}] | [{"b":2}] | [{"c":3}]| ...
-----|----------|-----------|----------|------
2    | ....
```

Is there an easy way to concat and merge these values using UDF, with result being
`[{"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3}]`?

I thought about doing string concatenating and regex replacing first, but the SQL would be quite verbose, so I'm looking into JS UDF now. However I'm lost at how to do it with arbitrary number of columns/args.  Appreciate your thoughts!

### EDIT 1

To clarify, for the UDF implementation, would be ideal if I can choose arbitrary number of args in arbitrary order, i.e.

- `func(col1, col2)` gives me `[{"a":1}, {"b":2}]`, and
- `func(col1, col2, col3)` gives me `[{"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c": 3}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the args selective, say, I can choose combine(col1, col2) or combine(col1, col2, col100)?
>
> func(col1, col2) gives me [{"a":1}, {"b":2}], and
> func(col1, col2, col3) gives me [{"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c": 3}].

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION combine(s ANY TYPE) AS (
  REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(s), r'\\"', '"')
);
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '{"a":1}' col1, '{"b":2}' col2, '{"c":3}' col3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, '{"d":4}' col1, '{"e":5}' col2, '{"f":6}' col3 
)
SELECT id, 
  combine([col1, col2]) combined_2columns,
  combine([col1, col2, col3]) combined_3columns
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
-- ORDER BY id
```

with output

```
Row id  combined_2columns       combined_3columns    
1   1   ["{"a":1}","{"b":2}"]   ["{"a":1}","{"b":2}","{"c":3}"]  
2   2   ["{"d":4}","{"e":5}"]   ["{"d":4}","{"e":5}","{"f":6}"]
```

Comment: Nice, in this case the args are the same type: an array of columns  --I was expecting a param list similar with CONCAT.  

Great answer as long as it works!

Comment: on second look this doesn't quite solve the issue as the original columns contain 'brackets' -- they're of formats of json *arrays*.

Comment: Just apply a little extra formatting. Quite simple! Answer gives you the core - do then whatever extra you need

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION combine(s ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(x ORDER BY OFFSET)
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT('%t', s), r'\)$', ''))) x WITH OFFSET
  WHERE OFFSET > 0
));
SELECT id, combine(t) AS combined_columns
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
ORDER BY id
```

You can test, play with it using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION combine(s ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(x ORDER BY OFFSET)
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT('%t', s), r'\)$', ''))) x WITH OFFSET
  WHERE OFFSET > 0
));
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '{"a":1}' col1, '{"b":2}' col2, '{"c":3}' col3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, '{"d":4}' col1, '{"e":5}' col2, '{"f":6}' col3 
)
SELECT id, combine(t) AS combined_columns
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
ORDER BY id
```

with result

```
Row id  combined_columns     
1   1   {"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3}    
2   2   {"d":4}, {"e":5}, {"f":6}
```

If you want combined value to be array - replace STRING_AGG() with ARRAY_AGG() and result will be

```
Row id  combined_columns     
1   1   {"a":1}  
        {"b":2}  
        {"c":3}  
2   2   {"d":4}  
        {"e":5}  
        {"f":6}
```

Obviously, above is applicable for any number of col(s), as long as first column is `id` and `col1 thru colx are all of type STRING` as it is stated in question. Otheriwse, above needs to be slightly adjusted - but those would be quite minor changes ...

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is it possible to make the args selective, say, I can choose  `combine(col1, col2)` or `combine(col1, col2, col100)`?

Comment: it is possible, but requires different implementation. your question was specifically asking for combining all cols. post new question with all new details and I (or someone else) will answer. Meantime, please vote up and accept if you see this answer helped you

Comment: apologies for the ambiguity, I wasn't clear on `I'm lost at how to do it with arbitrary number of columns/args`.  Clarified the Q.